# How do I copy a range into a temp workbook and return a reference to it with a vba function?

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following which errors on the "rTemp.Value = vaTemp" line. What am I doing wrong here? Am I on the right track?

```
Function CreateTempRange(rSource As range) As range
    ' Declarations
    Dim rTemp As range
    Dim vaTemp As Variant
    Dim wsTemp As Worksheet
    Dim wbTemp As Workbook

    ' Open temp worksheet
    Set wbTemp = Workbooks.Add
    Set wsTemp = wbTemp.Worksheets.Add

    ' Copy range into it and get a reference to the temp range
    vaTemp = rSource.Value
    Set rTemp = wsTemp.range("A1").Resize(UBound(vaTemp, 1), UBound(vaTemp, 2))
    rTemp.Value = vaTemp

    ' Return the temp range
    Set CreateTempRange = rTemp
End Function
```

Note: This function is intended to be used by other functions and not called directly from a cell.

Answer (score 1):

```
Set rTemp = wsTemp.range("A1").Resize(UBound(vaTemp, 1), UBound(vaTemp, 2)
```

There'll be a type mismatch here ... i'm not sure it really makes any sense. ubound(a,2) is used for multi-dimensional arrays not ranges.

I'm guessing you want to take the value in the cell specified then copy it many times depending on it's value. Is that correct?

Hopefully the below should give you an example to work with. If not edit your post and i'll see if i can help.

```
Function CreateTempRange(rSource As Range) As Range
    '' Declarations
    Dim rTemp As Range
    Dim vaTemp As Variant

    Dim wsTemp As Worksheet
    Dim wbTemp As Workbook

    '' Open temp worksheet
    Set wbTemp = Workbooks.Add
    Set wsTemp = wbTemp.Worksheets.Add

    '' Copy range into it and get a reference to the temp range
    vaTemp = rSource.Value
    ''Set rTemp = wsTemp.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(vaTemp, 1), UBound(vaTemp, 2))

    Dim iTemp As Integer
    On Error Resume Next
    iTemp = CInt(vaTemp)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If iTemp < 1 Then
      iTemp = 1
    End If
    Set rTemp = wsTemp.Range("A1:A" & iTemp)
    rTemp.Value = vaTemp

    '' Return the temp range
    Set CreateTempRange = rTemp
End Function

Sub test()

  Dim r As Range
  Dim x As Range
  Set r = ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
  Set x = CreateTempRange(r)

End Sub
```

Comment: My range will be a table not a single dimension. I just want to copy the range (rows and cols) to the temp worksheet and return a reference to it.

Comment: Ah, i was very confused what you wanted. I'm guessing this relates to some of your other questions. Can you post a question with some more details on what you are trying to achieve overall with this temp table and i'll see if i can make something a bit more useful.

Answer (score 1):

```
vaTemp = rSource.Value
```

As you aren't specifying the `RangeValueDataType` parameter to the Value method of the Range object, it will default to `xlRangeValueDefault` which, for non-empty ranges, will return an array of values. Therefore, the `UBound(..., 1)` and `UBound(..., 2)` parts make sense.

This would be easier:

```
Function CreateTempRange(rSource As range) As range
    ' Declarations
    Dim rTemp As range
    Dim wsTemp As Worksheet
    Dim wbTemp As Workbook

    ' Open temp worksheet
    Set wbTemp = Workbooks.Add
    Set wsTemp = wbTemp.Worksheets.Add

    ' Create new range on that sheet starting at cell A1
    Set rTemp = wsTemp.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(rSource.Rows.Count, _
        rSource.Columns.Count))
    rTemp.Value = rSource.Value

    ' Return the temp range
    Set CreateTempRange = rTemp
End Function
```

You would still need some code to deal with ranges which consist of multiple areas (use the `Areas.Count` property to check for that)

Comment: I'm still getting a type mismatch on that line. Did this work for you?

Comment: Works OK for me in Excel 2003

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this

```
Function CreateTempRange(src As Range) As Range

Dim wbk As Workbook: Set wbk = Workbooks.Add
Dim sht As Worksheet: Set sht = wbk.Worksheets.Add

Call src.Copy(sht.Cells(1, 1))

Set CreateTempRange = Range(rSource.Address).Offset(1 - rSource.Row, 1 - rSource.Column)

End Function
```

**Explanation of the last line of code (as requested):-**

`Range(rSource.Address)` - this refers to the range on the current worksheet (containing the code) with the same local address as the source range, so if the the source range is C3:E5 on 'Sheet X' then `Range(rSource.Address)` refers to C3:E5 on the current sheet.

Since we pasted the copied range into the current sheet starting at cell A1 rather than cell C3 (I assume this is your requirement), we then need to offset this reference accordingly.  The `.Offset(1 - rSource.Row, 1 - rSource.Column)` offsets this range negatively by both the row index (3) minus 1 and column index (C or 3) minus 1 of the source range, so that the final resulting reference starts with cell A1 and keeps the same dimensions as the source range.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Can you explain what exactly is going on here? I'm not understanding the use of offset. You have an answer similar to this in another open question of mine. I commented there that it looks like the ranges share the same reference after this. Is that true? thanks for the help

Comment: Basically I'm using the local address of the source range to get its dimensions, getting a reference to the equivalent range on the target sheet and offsetting it back to start at cell A1, which gives a reference to the pasted data.  The resulting references are completely seperate.

Answer (score 0):

Deano, that code works for me as written.  What is the error you're getting?

Comment: When stepping through the code, execution stops on the line in question.

Comment: Gah! I think I figured it out. I'm calling this function from within another function. Is this allowed? When writing a test Sub it worked fine.

Comment: Calling it from a function should not be a problem.

<code>Function TestIT()
    
    Dim rng As Range
    
    Set rng = CreateTempRange(ActiveSheet.Range("A1:C3"))
    
    TestIT = rng(2)
    
End Function</code>

Works.